# Assigning values to a column based on condition using np.where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Though the question seems very similar but I am stuck a this . Below is the sample of data. I want to add number of productView and Order where productView < Order.

```
           productView  order
userId      
A                4.5    5.0
B               1.5     2.5
C               4.0     2.0
D                2.0    3.0
```

I tried following code but its throwing error

```
order_Segemnt.productView=np.where(order_Segment[order_Segment.productView< order_Segment.order]['productView'],order_Segment.productView+order_Segment.order, order_Segment.productView)
```

Error which I am getting is this

```
Error- ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (408,) (7464,) (7464,)
```

How to achieve my objective??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Syntax* -

```
np.where(condition, value1, value2)
```

*Solution* -

```
np.where(
   df.productView < df.order, df.productView + df.order, df.productView
)
array([9.5, 4. , 4. , 5. ])
```

As an efficient alternative, you can use `loc`:

```
m = df.productView < df.order
df.loc[m, 'productView'] = df.loc[m, ['productView', 'order']].sum(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `mask`

```
df['New']=df.productView.mask(df.order>df.productView,df.sum(1))
df
Out[271]: 
        productView  order  New
userId                         
A               4.5    5.0  9.5
B               1.5    2.5  4.0
C               4.0    2.0  4.0
D               2.0    3.0  5.0
```